# Get Physical NIC's Mac Addresses on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, c

I am trying to get the mac addresses of a Linux machine.  I only want the physical NIC's though, not the virtual ones.  I have been doing some searching and maybe I am not punching in the right terms to find something on Google.  I know about ifconfig -a to show information about NIC's but I don't see a way at the moment to differentiate physical vs virtual.  Also I am going to want to program this into C eventually, so something that is C compatible would be amazing.

Thanks.  Happy to answer any and all questions.

Comment: Have you tried http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter ? It has a serial option which might only show hardware information.

Comment: By physical NICs you mean anything that could be plugged in *any* bus of the device you're referring to? That means you'd have to scan *all* buses or at least read equivalent information from `/sys`. Is this really the scope or are we actually talking about USB and PCI buses only?

Answer (score 4):

*lshw* will do this for you:

```
  sudo lshw -C network
```

For instance, my wifi card is displayed as follows:

```
 *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 24
   serial: c8:f7:33:4c:cc:e1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.11.0-15-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:47 memory:e2500000-e2501fff
```

The MAC address is, of course, the serial number. Notice that, even if you change the apparent MC address of the wifi card with *macchanger*, *lshw* will still display the true MAC address, contrary to *ifconfig*, which displays the changed one. Also, there is no mention of interfaces built on this piece of hardware.

Lastly, according to its man page, *lshw*...

> ...currently  supports  DMI  (x86  and IA-64 only), OpenFirmware device tree (PowerPC only), PCI/AGP, CPUID
>          (x86), IDE/ATA/ATAPI, PCMCIA (only tested on x86), SCSI and USB.

which is the most complete coverage I could find.

Comment: Is there a way to get this information without sudo access?

Comment: @MasterGberry Not that I know.